# Need help to change the button function

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i know that my question is stupid a bit, but i really dont know the coding.
I need help with source code which i found somewhere in network, i dont know coding well and all what i want to do is just change the button function to redirect for site which i want to put in code.
Bascially was used to showing some reward video ads, which i removed from code but have no idea how to change the button function.
I will be very grateful for any help from your side.
Button is called btnMore, below is main activity class and activity main.xml
Thanks for any help from your side.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String[] Name_Item;
private int index;
private ImageButton btnMore;
private boolean detectNetwork ;
private    MyListData[] myListData ;
private  SharedPref sharedpref;
private final  Handler mHandler = new Handler();
Snackbar snackbar ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sharedpref = new SharedPref(this);
    if(sharedpref.loadNightModeState()) {
        setTheme(R.style.darktheme);
    }
    else  setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Setup Custom Consent
    // check font
    FontControle fontControle= new FontControle(this);
    fontControle.checked();


    //toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.showOverflowMenu();





    detectNetwork= new Utils(this).isConnectingToInternet();
    LinearLayout showMore = findViewById(R.id.ShowMore);
    btnMore= findViewById(R.id.btnShowMore);


    Name_Item=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Name_item);
    index =sharedpref.LoadInt("index");
    int maxindex = Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.MaxIndex));

    if (index== -1){
        sharedpref.SaveInt("index",6);
        index=6;
        if (maxindex ==6) showMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else if (index== maxindex) showMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //ads Banner
    if (AdsConfig.ENABLE_ADMOB)
        AdsBanner.newInstance(this).loadBannerAdView((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_ad));
    else
        AdsBanner.newInstance(this).LoadBannerFbview( findViewById(R.id.ad_applovin));


    Takeguide();

    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 200);
    btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (detectNetwork) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Show More")
                        .setMessage("Watch video ads for show more?")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();

            } else {
                snackBar("No Internet ,Enable wifi or connection network");
            }
        }});



<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:transitionName="nameApp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ads"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ShowMore">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ShowMore"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/backmore"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/MoreItemText"
        android:textColor="?attr/blue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:fontFamily="serif" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnShowMore"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gift"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Show"
        android:textColor="?attr/Black" />

</LinearLayout>


<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/customSnac"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ShowMore"></androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <com.applovin.adview.AppLovinAdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_applovin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/Black">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: you need to update the `onClick` method for that button.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide

Comment: ... and please have a look at [TOUR], [ASK] and how to write a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

There you have a listener

"btnMore.setOnClickListener"

That reacts to click

The function:
"public void onClick(View v)"

Is the code that is triggered when button its clicked

So you can change the code inside "onClick"

Comment: Hello, thanks for you reply i didnt specified what i mean, i just edited the post right now. I want to edit that button to redirect function from link, which i want to put in code.

Comment: What code should i put there, to get function which will open the site from link which i paste inside.